# Python: How to create diff/patch files between 2 revisions for a single URL?

Tags: python, svn, version-control, diff

I would like to create a diff (patch) file between two revisions for a single SVN URL, including lines of unified context.

Basically I need to provide a Python method to achieve the following:

URL to the SVN repository
number for first (before) revision
number for second (after) revision

The output I require is as follows:

number of lines of code in head revision
number of changed files

actual diff files.

How can I do this using Python?  I see many similar questions here but none specifically on how to achieve this in Python.  Can anyone suggest some libraries/code to help accomplish this?

Comment: I'm wondering if difflib would be of any help?  http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html#module-difflib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed [pysvn](http://pysvn.tigris.org/) offers [diff](http://pysvn.tigris.org/docs/pysvn_prog_ref.html#pysvn_client_diff) method.  I think this is exactly what you need.

Comment: Do you know if there is something already available that uses pysvn or do I have to create it from scratch?

Comment: This pysvn tool looks very promising.  I'm going to check it out and see how much custom code I need to get my work done.  Thanks!